# jqGrid save Grid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have my grid loaded with all rows in edit mode already.  I also have a a addrow button.  My issue is having the entire grid sent to the database for edits and also if the user adds a row.  I tried the following but 'data' is empty its just [].

```
function SaveAll() {
var localGridData = $("#grid").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'data');
sendData(localGridData);
}

<input type="button" value"Save" onclick="SaveAll()" />
```

I then want it to pass it to my method called senddata = function(data){...

Comment: You've missed a quote, should be: `$("#grid").jqGrid(...)`, just a notice.

Comment: Yeah, its correct in my method I typoed it here.

Comment: Any Ideas on this guys?

Comment: Can you reproduce it in jsfiddle with minimum code?

Comment: Not so much since I have to work off a VM.

Comment: Is my code not right for even saving a row in the grid?

Comment: This is why nobody answers - you didn't supply enough information, your code seems to be OK and it's not clear from description what else could be wrong. That is why I've asked for more details - to provide a working jsfiddle with the reproduced issue. I've created a simple [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/iluzyanin/a0zuctbq/) for you so you could update it according to your actual code and reproduce the issue.

Comment: Ok thanks for the example.  I created somewhat on how I have it set to load the whole grid in edit mode but can't get it to work with my gridcomplete function.  I commented it out as you can see here.  [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/marine1988/a0zuctbq/17/)

Comment: Here, I've updated your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/iluzyanin/a0zuctbq/19/) so it would not show errors, what's next?

Comment: Lemme see whats in localGridData.  Did you see my save methods I had in there?

Comment: Ok I added more of what I am using in my form.  Can't get addrow to work now.

Comment: From my review of my code I found what was part of the problem and that was I was using the wrong data object paramter.  It was called userData not data.  So I changed it and now get only my footer data instead of the grid data.

Comment: So did you resolve your issue? I cant view your code right now

Comment: Not so much.  I ran the changes and it would not run but noticed I was calling my userData: property 'data' instead of 'userdata'.  So now I get data back but its only my footer data.

Comment: that was contained in my json reader property. jsonReader: {userData: "userdata"}

Comment: Still no resolution.  Issue is my userdata is utilized to populate my footer. That I can get but when trying to get the changed values I get nothing back.

Comment: I fixed it but can't post my answer for some reason.